# SCSI Read(10) on a Physical Drive on Windows

Tags: c, winapi

I tried issuing a SCSI Read(10) command to a physical drive on a Windows 7 machine. Below is the code snippet that I am using.  It is failing with error code 87.

```
void scsi_read() 
{

 const UCHAR cdb[10] = { 0x28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 0 };
 UCHAR buf[512];
 BYTE senseBuf[196];
 const int SENSE_LENGTH = 196;
 LPCSTR fname = "\\\\.\\E:";
 HANDLE fh; 
 DWORD ioctl_bytes;
 DWORD err = 0;

 SCSI_PASS_THROUGH s = {0};
 memcpy(s.Cdb, cdb, sizeof(cdb));
 s.CdbLength = 10;
 s.DataIn = SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN;
 s.TimeOutValue = 30;
 s.Length = sizeof(SCSI_PASS_THROUGH);  
 s.ScsiStatus         = 0x00;
 s.SenseInfoOffset =  senseBuf;
 s.SenseInfoLength  = SENSE_LENGTH;
 s.DataBufferOffset = buf;
 s.DataTransferLength = 512;

 fh = CreateFile("\\\\.\\E:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
 if(fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Could not open %s file, error %d\n", fname, GetLastError());
    return (FALSE);
 }

 int ret = DeviceIoControl(fh,IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH, &s,sizeof(s), //scsiPassThrough.sizeof,
                                &s,
                                sizeof(s),
                                &ioctl_bytes,
                                NULL);

 printf("ret %d",(int)ret);                                    
 if (ret==1) {
    printf("OK");
 }
 else {

    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Last error code %u\n", err);
    printf("Return size %d\n", ioctl_bytes);
    printf("Sense data\n");
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("\t%x", senseBuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
 CloseHandle(fh);
}
```

Error: Hex dumps are printed in the output

[image: Code Output]

Answer (score 3):

you got error code 87 - `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because code totally wrong.

for example:

```
const UCHAR cdb[10] = { 0x28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 0 };
```

but `512` is `> 255` (`MAXUCHAR`) are you not got compiler warning here ?

```
warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'const UCHAR'
```

look at this line !

```
s.DataBufferOffset = buf;
```

from [`SCSI_PASS_THROUGH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565345(v=vs.85).aspx) structure:

> **DataBufferOffset**
>
> Contains an offset from the beginning of this structure to the data
>   buffer. The offset must respect the data alignment requirements of the
>   device.

so **offset** to buffer, not **pointer** to buffer

for use this correct you code need be like this:

```
struct MY_DATA : SCSI_PASS_THROUGH 
{
    UCHAR buf[512];
} s;

s.DataBufferOffset = FIELD_OFFSET(MY_DATA, buf);
```

but better use [`SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565346(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560521(v=vs.85).aspx)

you hardcode sector size (512), when need get it at runtime. and how you initialize `CDB` ?!? at all unclear what you try todo.

working code example (sorry but on `c++` instead `c`)

```
#define _NTSCSI_USER_MODE_
#include <scsi.h>
#include <ntddscsi.h>

BOOL scsi_read(HANDLE fh, PVOID buf, DWORD cb, ULONGLONG LogicalBlock, ULONG TransferBlocks)
{
    SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT s = { 
        sizeof(SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN, cb, 30, buf
    };

    union {
        PUCHAR Cdb;
        CDB::_CDB10* Cdb10;
        CDB::_CDB16* Cdb16;
    };

    Cdb = s.Cdb;

    if (MAXULONG < LogicalBlock || MAXUSHORT < TransferBlocks)
    {
        s.CdbLength = sizeof(CDB::_CDB16);
        Cdb16->OperationCode = SCSIOP_READ16;
        *(ULONGLONG*)Cdb16->LogicalBlock = _byteswap_uint64(LogicalBlock);
        *(ULONG*)Cdb16->TransferLength = _byteswap_ulong(TransferBlocks);
    }
    else
    {
        s.CdbLength = sizeof(CDB::_CDB10);
        Cdb10->OperationCode = SCSIOP_READ;
        *(ULONG*)&Cdb10->LogicalBlockByte0 = _byteswap_ulong((ULONG)LogicalBlock);
        *(USHORT*)&Cdb10->TransferBlocksMsb = _byteswap_ushort((USHORT)TransferBlocks);
    }

    DWORD ioctl_bytes;

    return DeviceIoControl(fh, IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT, &s, sizeof(s), &s, sizeof(s), &ioctl_bytes, NULL);
}

BOOL test_scsi_read(PCWSTR fname) 
{
    BOOL fOk = FALSE;

    HANDLE fh = CreateFileW(fname, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        DWORD ioctl_bytes;

        DISK_GEOMETRY_EX dg;

        if (DeviceIoControl(fh, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, NULL, 0, &dg, sizeof(dg), &ioctl_bytes, 0))
        {
            // 16 sectors for example
            ULONG cb = 16 * dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector;

            if (PVOID buf = new CHAR[cb])
            {
                // read first 16 sectors
                fOk = scsi_read(fh, buf, cb, 0, 16);

                if (ULONGLONG LogicalBlock = dg.DiskSize.QuadPart / dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector)
                {
                    // read last sector
                    fOk = scsi_read(fh, buf, dg.Geometry.BytesPerSector, LogicalBlock - 1, 1);
                }

                delete buf;
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(fh);
    }

    return fOk;
}
    test_scsi_read(L"\\\\?\\e:");
```