# Max transfer size of SCSI Read(10) on a Physical Drive

Tags: scsi, deviceiocontrol

Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_storage_adapter_descriptor), IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY with StorageAdapterProperty can be used to get the max transfer size of per SCSI Read(10) command.

In [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460806/4898705), 16 sectors are read from start of lba. I tried to modify the number and in my Win7 environment, the max number is 256 sector through SATA and 128 sector through bridge (SATA-USB) to a SSD, which match the result using IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY with StorageAdapterProperty.

As far as I know, when installing OS (win7, win10, macOS), a device can receive a SCSI Read(10) command up to 2048 sector. I wonder which layer limits the transfer size (operating system/device driver...) and is there any way to bypass the layer to send a SCSI Read(10) command longer than the limitation at a time?